# Unable to reset Tic Tac Toe game in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, storyboard

I am following a YouTube guide and the game works in the video, but for me the game won't reset. The alerts are working and showing the winner, but the reset function isn't. I have the loadBoard() in the beginning and func reset() { board.removeAll() loadBoard() in the end, help please

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
    var currentPlayer = ""
    var board = [String]()
    var rules = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadBoard()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let index = buttons.index(of: sender)!
        
        if !board[index].isEmpty {
            return
        }
        
        if currentPlayer == "X" {
            sender.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
            currentPlayer = "O"
            board[index] = "X"
        } else {
            sender.setTitle("O", for: .normal)
            currentPlayer = "X"
            board[index] = "O"
        }
        whoWins()
    }
    
    func whoWins() {
        for rule in rules {
            let player1 = board[rule[0]]
            let player2 = board[rule[1]]
            let player3 = board[rule[2]]
            if player1 == player2, player2 == player3, !player1.isEmpty {
                print("Winner is \(player2)")
                showAlert(msg: "Good job \(player3) You have won ")
                return
            }
        }
        if !board.contains("") {
            showAlert(msg: "It is a tie!")
        }
    }
    
    func showAlert(msg : String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
            _ in self.reset()
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func reset() {
        board.removeAll()
        loadBoard()
        
        for button in buttons {
            button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
    
    func loadBoard(){
        for _ in 0..<buttons.count {
            board.append("")
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What happens when you call the reset function? Have you tried adding a print statement at the beginning of the reset button to make sure it is getting called?

Comment: Where is the code that populates your `buttons` array? How are you adding your buttons to the screen?

Comment: on the storyboard/uikit I connect all buttons to the  @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]! its a button collection

Comment: I ran your code and it works for me. What happens when you set a breakpoint on the line that says `button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)`?

Comment: With the breakpoint there nothing happens, the game is won but does not reset.

Comment: Try using empty String `""` instead of `nil` in `button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)`

Comment: omg thank you so much empty string worked

Comment: Vacawama, you should post your response and an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the button title to `nil` has no effect.  Perhaps this worked in an earlier version of iOS, but now it seems to make no change to the title.

Use empty `String` `""` instead to blank out the button's title:

```
button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
```